# Updating property of a large observable collection on dispatcher

Tags: wpf

I have a large observable collection of lets say an object person with property IsManager.This is binded on a data grid. Now on some event I need to update this property.Since the event handler is handling event on background thread, I need to update it on Dispatcher. I am calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with background priority.Since this collection is large(More than 50000 records), The UI becomes sluggish for other operations like grid scolling.

Do we have some approch that can resolve this..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

An `ObservableCollection<T>` bound to a grid with 50000 rows will always cause you lots of problems with updates.

A better solution is not to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` use a `List<T>` ,and then when you need to apply updates, then change the `ItemsSource` property of the grid with a brand new new `List<T>` (via a binding expression).

If you replace the `ItemsSource` then the Grid will only create row containers for the grids viewport, which will hog the UI thread much much less (assuming virtualization has been applied to the grid)